# Umbraco Carousel Content

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I am putting together my first Umbraco project and starting to pick it up nicely. I am a little stuck at creating an appropriate repeatable field for a Carousel with text, image and a link but also how to output that in a template.

I come from a Craft CMS / Expression Engine background and would usually use a repeatable field like Matrix or Grid for such a task.

Any help would be fantastic!

Thanks!
-Graham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check **Nested Content** package (it will be included in Umbraco Core soon): https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/ and then create appropriate document type and use it inside new data type for inserting multiple slides into your desired page / node.

Other way can be to create simple tree structure with slides repository (e.g. under desired node) and then repeating through them to render carousel on your page. However, first solution is more appropriate, efficient, less "expensive" from the performance perspective in time.

Of course, you could also use the **Grid Layout** editor: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout. It also may contain other editors inside, so it depends from the requirements and personal preferences of the users / editors.

Comment: Do agree with @Marcin , the only thing i do extra is if the slider is going to be used on on page only then use the Archetype package i.e. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/ or the nested content above. If i am making one that will be used site wide or by more that one page then i go with a tree structure with slides more in another parent node i call settings to separate actual pages from "system" pages as i call them.